# Spring Boot Service 404 error Java consuming a service

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I'am trying to consume a service but i got the next error when a try to consume the services but spring no give any error only the web console, am not sure where is the problem are, before a had a cors origins  problem but i fixed in my config file that it's bellow.

```
zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET http://localhost:8080/api/book-list 404

core.js:4442 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/book-list", ok: false, …}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController  
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")  
@RequestMapping(value="/api")  
public class Controller {
    @Autowired  
    private BookService bookservice;
    @PostMapping("save-book")  
    public boolean SaveBook(@RequestBody Book book) {  
         return bookservice.SaveBook(book);   
    }
    @GetMapping("book-list")  
    public List<Book> AllBooks() {  
         return bookservice.GetBooks();         
    }
    @DeleteMapping("delete-book/{Id}")  
    public boolean DeleteBook(@PathVariable("Id") int Id,Book book) {  
        book.SetBookId(Id);  
        return bookservice.DeleteBooks(book);  
    }
    @GetMapping("book/{Id}")  
    public List<Book> AllBooksById(@PathVariable("Id") int Id,Book book) {  
         book.SetBookId(Id);  
         return bookservice.GetBookByID(book);    
    }
    @PostMapping("update-book/{Id}")  
    public boolean UpdateBook(@RequestBody Book book,@PathVariable("Id") int Id) {  
        book.SetBookId(Id);  
        return bookservice.UpdateBook(book);  
    } 
}
```

service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';  
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/'; 
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }  
  GetBookList(): Observable<any> {  
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`+'book-list');  
  }
  CreateBook(student: object): Observable<object> {  
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`+'save-book', student);  
  }  
  DeleteBook(id: number): Observable<any> {  
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/delete-book/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });  
  }  
  GetBook(id: number): Observable<Object> {  
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/book/${id}`);  
  }  
  UpdateBook(id: number, value: any): Observable<Object> {  
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/update-book/${id}`, value);  
  }  
}
```

My cors config file. I think that the problem is here but i'm not sure:

```
@SpringBootApplication  
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableWebMvc
public class BookAplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        SpringApplication.run(BookAplication.class, args);  
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            }           
        };          
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/api/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/api/"); 
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Remove `@Configuration`, remove `@EnableWebMvc` and remove the `addResourceHandlers` method. Relaunch the application. You can remove `implements WebMvcConfigurer` as well.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to put a "/" before your requestmappings. Change from "save-book" to "/save-book". The other ones too.

Comment: @M.Deinum the error is the same and in the spring console got "No mapping for GET /api/book-list"